# Persistent Collection not visible in layout

Tags: isis

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PgOSqf7rYE) video on persisting bidirectional collections with Apache Isis. For some reasons it doesn't work for me (my context is slightly different from the video as I started from the maven starter project). If I look up the `CustomerOrder` by from a newly introduced `CustomerOrders`, it finds `CustomerOrders` that point to the `Customer`. Also, the CustomerOrder appears in swagger-ui when throwing requests at it. However, my table in the customer view stays empty? This why I do see the table itself (due `unreferencedCollections="true"`). Did I miss something from the video? Where do I start debugging?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just when you post it, after an hour of frustration, you figure out you were simply hiding the table. Feeling very ashamed now ;-)

Comment: It is a good practice to share the answer even of your own questions. This helps other users in the future.

Comment: I am giving the answer to my own question. The video displays the the tables in tabbed panes, in the default template they are not in tabs, but under a selection toggle. This is what I mean with "hiding". Because I came from the video, I expected the table to be directly visible, but you had to select it first. Now remove that downvote ...

Comment: I think that @martin-g was just thanking you.my thanks too for sharing your answer...